# how do I render a z3c.form form with independent subforms?

Tags: plone, z3c.form

I want to have a page that has multiple independent forms on it - in my case, there are no submittable form fields but instead each subform has some HTML content and then a button. The main form has no buttons.

The z3c.form docs say a custom template is needed to render the subform(s). On the other hand, apparently the plone.z3c.form package provides a default subform template and registers that as an adapter that can be used.

How do I use the default (z3c.form and/or plone.z3c.form) templates to render a form with subform(s)?

Comment: z3c.form subform in the end are all part of a big unique form. If you really need separate forms stay on the custom view way and render different forms.

Comment: Did you read all of [this](https://github.com/zopefoundation/z3c.form/blob/master/src/z3c/form/subform.txt), perhaps "Context-free subforms" is relavant?

Comment: I did; the actual rendering details are however omitted in that document; hence the question.

Comment: Well, to be precise, the subform document uses templates from tests/ that can be examined, but I was hoping some built-in templates from plone.z3c.form could be used somehow.